# How to put on footwraps correctly?

Tags: footwear

In [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/4716/3143) answer @Vorac mentions [footwraps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footwraps). So I wondered, if I want to try them, how should I put them on?

Does anyone have experience with this? Are there different methods to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## портянки (portyanki)

[image]

The Russian army wore portyanki (footcloths) up until the ministry of defence abolished them in 2008. There's an interesting article about them [here](http://russiapedia.rt.com/of-russian-origin/portyanki/), the author of which apparently wore portyanki for 695 days in the army.<sup>1</sup>

### How to put on footcloths:

- spread the piece of cloth (40cm x 90cm) flat on the floor;
- put the foot closer to the edge of the cloth to wrap the edge around the big toe (the left foot should be closer to the left edge – and the right foot – to the right) ;
- take the side of the rag and wrap it tight around the foot;
- take the back of the rag and wrap it tightly around the leg;
- pull the edge to adjust tightness and bend it behind the rest of the cloth;
- put your boots on.

[image]

---

<sup>1 [Russiapedia. *Of Russian origin:* **Portyanki.**](http://russiapedia.rt.com/of-russian-origin/portyanki/)</sup>

Properly tying a portyanki takes a lot of practice, and improperly tying them can result in some serious blisters and foot sores. Learning how to properly and quickly tie a portyanki was the first thing a rookie in the Russian army had to learn at the beginning of his military career.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this reminds me of the little plastic soldiers I had when I was a kid, turns out they must of been wearing foot wraps and I didn't know

Comment: There are apparently a lot of [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) (in russian) on how to tie a portyanki. They appear to be quite the tradition in Russia.